# extracting columns from list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

R newbie here. I know similar question have been asked before, but I just can't figure it out, so here it comes. I have a list of lists created by importing some datafiles from Matlab to R. I used lapply repeatedly to get top a list of datalists, and got it to look like this (extract for the first two datalists):

```
       [[1]]
    [[1]]$Data
    , , 1
    
                 [,1]             
    opsy  "1"              
    st    List,11                  
    nr    280              
    var1      Numeric,280      
    var2      Numeric,280      
    var3      Numeric,280      
    ...         
    
    
       [[2]]
    [[2]]$Data
    , , 1
    
                 [,1]             
    opsy   "2"              
    st     List,11                  
    nr     555              
    var1        Numeric,555      
    var2        Numeric,555      
    var3        Numeric,555      
    ...          

The str(my_top_list[[1]]$Data) looks as follows:

List of 15
 $ : chr [1, 1] "1"
 $ : chr [1, 1] "20191202T103203"
 $ :List of 11
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "Ariel"
  ..$ : num [1, 1:3] 255 255 255
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 72
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 42
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 30
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 42
  .. ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 4 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "reference" "fixation" "probabilities" "lotteryValues"
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 172 101
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 71 55
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 42 41
  .. ..$ :List of 6
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 64 64
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 92 64
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 156 64
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 156 64
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 156 64
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:2] 156 64
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 6 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Digit1" "Digit2" "Digit3" "Digit4" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 4 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "reference" "fixation" "probabilities" "lotteryValues"
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "$5"
  .. ..$ : chr[0 , 1] 
  .. ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 2 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "reference" "fixation"
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 150
  .. ..$ : num [1, 1] 300
  .. ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 2 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "width" "height"
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : num [1, 1] 10
  ..$ : num [1, 1:4] 0 0 1440 900
  ..$ : num [1, 1] 10
  ..$ : num [1, 1] 1
  ..$ : num [1, 1] 1
  ..- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 11 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "fontName" "fontColor" "fontSize" "textDims" ...
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "blue"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "red"
 $ : num [1, 1] 280
 $ : num [1, 1:280] 99 75 150 270 220 257 8 16 237 279 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 22.2 22.2 7.85 26.4 7.85 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 0.58 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : num [1:280, 1] 22.2 11.1 5.55 15.7 5.55 ...
 $ : num [1, 1:280] 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ : num [1, 1:280] 0.433 0.704 3.036 1.992 0.718 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 15 1 1
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:15] "observer" "date" "stimulus" "colorKey" ...
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 NULL
```

I would need to extract some variables from each of the objects [[i]]$Data, say var1 and var3, assign as an id the value stored in opsy, and get this into a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   id  var1    var3
    1   45     0.2
    1   77     0.11
    1   33     0.45
   ...  ..      ...
    2   44     0.99
    2   21     0.01
   ...  ..     ..
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Max

Comment: It's hard to tell what structures you have. What is the class of `your_top_list[[i]]$Data`? It's printing behavior doesn't look like an array or a data frame. Could you make your example reproducible, sharing `dput(your_top_list[[1]]$Data)`, or if that's too big at least `str(your_top_list[[1]]$Data)`?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the str() you suggest--does this help?

Comment: Looks like you have complicated list in which case having `dput` would be helpful. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)